# set dynamic host and port for Referer with HTTPRequestDefaults

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

How can I set dynamic host and port for Referer with HTTPRequestDefaults?

I set HTTPRequestDefaults and all hosts and ports of all http requests are blank, so when running the Jmeter they get the value from HTTPRequestDefaults  but all referers are static.

forexample if referer is http://172.16.23.10:9080/mycontext/home-login.action?justLogin=true , then I want the referer to read 172.16.23.10 and 9080 from http request default

Note: I know I can use dynamic variables but I want to now if there's a solution with httprequestdefault.

Comment: is it referrer that you want to make dynamic ?

Comment: @UBIK LOAD PACK  yes of course. forexample if referer is `http://172.16.23.10:9080/mycontext/home-login.action?justLogin=true` , then I want the referer to read 172.16.23.10 and 9080 from http request default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this:

- Define 2 variables host and port that you'll use in [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)
- Add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as child of [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) and define in it the referrer as:

> http://${host}:${port}/mycontext/home-login.action?justLogin=true

Comment: I told I don't want to use variables. I want to use the host and port which I set in httprequestDefault in other requests

Comment: In this case it's just not possible